# My Supabase tables of schema public became inaccessible by API

Tags: supabase

We have set up a [Supabase](https://supabase.com/) database project (using their hosted service), and later requested through their support that they enable the new [resumable uploads feature](https://supabase.com/blog/storage-v3-resumable-uploads) in our project. Afterwards, all our tables in the `public` database schema are no longer accessible by API. Tables in the `storage` database schema are still accessible though.

Example, for a table called `programme`:

```
curl 'https://your-project-ref-id.supabase.co/rest/v1/programme?select=*' -H "apikey: YOUR_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR-AUTH-TOKEN"

{
  "code":"42P01",
  "details":null,
  "hint":null,
  "message":"relation \"storage.programme\" does not exist"
}
```

For similar requests, I would get this error message:

```
{
  "code":"PGRST106",
  "details":null,
  "hint":null,
  "message":"The schema must be one of the following: storage"
}
```

Another symptom is that the `public` schema's tables have vanished from the auto-generated Supabase API docs.

The `public` schema is however still listed as an exposed API schema in the Supabase project settings.

What could cause this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by accidental changes to the `authenticator` role in your PostgreSQL database. Whether this is indeed caused by a bug in the Supabase process that deploys the  resumable uploads feature, I don't really know, but I suspect it.

To check whether this is the cause in your case, run the following query:

```
SELECT setrole::regrole, setconfig
  FROM pg_db_role_setting 
  WHERE setrole::regrole = 'authenticator'::regrole;
```

If you see an output like this that does *not* include `public` in the role's database schemas, you have found the issue right there:

```
setrole        | setconfig
---------------+--------------------------------------------------------
authenticator  | {
               |   "session_preload_libraries=supautils, safeupdate",
               |   statement_timeout=8s,
               |   pgrst.db_schemas=storage
               | }
```

This setting is overriding the UI config, where, as you said, `public` is still included as a schema to expose by API. Or more precisely, the UI has `public` hardcoded into it, so that it does not reflect changes to or allow to make changes to its status of API exposure. Because it was intended in the Supabase that `public` is always exposed by API.

To correct this issue, you would add the `public` schema back to the schemas accessible by the `authenticator` role, including it in addition to the schemas listed there so far. In our case:

```
ALTER ROLE authenticator SET pgrst.db_schemas = 'public, storage';
NOTIFY pgrst;
```

This fixed API exposure of all `public` schema tables immediately, and these tables are also again included in the auto-generated API documentation in the Supabase backend.

Note that the modified role is only `authenticator`, not also the usual `authenticated` or `anon` roles you come into contact with in the Supabase PostgreSQL database. This is because the actual connection of an API request to the database is indeed made via role `authenticator`, which is a technicality of the PostgREST implementation:

> [T]he anon and authenticated do NOT need explicit permissions to connect to the [database] […], because the connection from PostgREST is actually executed with the `authenticator` role and then it just switches to `anon` or `authenticated` once it's already connected. ([source](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/4833#issuecomment-1006670378))

*(Credits: Worked out together with Steve from Supabase support. Thank you Steve!)*